# how can I pass a parameter I read from a file in a batch file to a program call in the same batch file?

Tags: parameters, batch-file

In my batch program  can sucessfully read from a file like this:

```
for /f %%a in (crc.txt) do (
@echo CRC read in from file is %%a now
)
```

where `%%a` is printed out as being `0xCD0134DE`

Now i want to pass in `%%a` into a C program call in the same batch file:

`../myprogram %%a`

Problem is myprogram interprets the `%%a` argument as being `'%a'` (I know this as I print out the argument as soon as myprogram starts. I've tried

```
../myprogram %a         //program thinks the argument is 'a'
../myprogram a          //program thinks the argument is 'a'
```

ie I don't get the value of `0xCD0134DE` as being passed in.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for /f %%a in (crc.txt) do (
    @echo CRC read in from file is %%a now
    ../myprogram %%a
)
```

`%%a` is only in scope for the `for` loop. If you need to use value this throughout the script, then set a local environment variable to hold the value:

```
for /f %%a in (crc.txt) do (
    set CRC=%%a
)
@echo CRC read in from file is %CRC% now
```

Comment: priting %%a in the loop gives us: 0xCFCE99A2

Comment: oop, printing %CRC% as you suggested comes out with:

Comment: CRC read in from file is  now
I'm guessing I need to make the variable CRC global somehow.

Comment: your first suggestion - I made the call to the program inside the 'Do (' bit.